# MigraDoc picture on a picture on a pcture

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have a cover page, where I have a picture which fills most of the page.

On that picture I have placed another picture which is dynamic, but onto those two pictures I need to place one more small logo picture, and that’s where it goes wrong (logo picture ends up in bottom right border of second layer picture).

**First layer picture**

```
var myImage = section.AddImage(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Forside.png"));
            myImage.Height = "23cm";
            myImage.Width = "21cm";
            myImage.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
            myImage.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Page;
            myImage.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
```

**Second layer picture**

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image image1 = section.AddImage(@model.UrlImage);
                image1.Width = "15.5cm";
                image1.Height = "8cm";

                image1.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Character;
                image1.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
                image1.Left = Unit.FromCentimeter(0.2);
                image1.Top = Unit.FromCentimeter(8.6);
```

**Third layer picture**

```
    var image4 = section.AddImage(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/sun icon.png"));
    image4.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Character;
    image4.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
    image4.WrapFormat.DistanceLeft = Unit.FromCentimeter(0.2);
    image4.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = Unit.FromCentimeter(6.6);
    image4.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code also for the 3rd layer:

```
myImage.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
myImage.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Page;
```

Calculate the absolute position for the 3rd layer picture, that should work.